# Moving data from one sheet to multiple sheets - vba

Tags: vba

I have some code that creates worksheets based on a cell value in a column and then I have the below code which will scan the same column and move the entire row of that sheet to the matching sheet name.

```
Sub CopyRowData()

'Declare variables
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim shSource As Worksheet
Dim shTarget1 As Worksheet
Dim shTarget2 As Worksheet
Dim shTarget3 As Worksheet
Dim shTarget4 As Worksheet
Dim shTarget5 As Worksheet
Dim shTarget6 As Worksheet

'Assign string values to variables
Set shSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1")
Set shTarget1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2")
Set shTarget2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("3")
Set shTarget3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("4")
Set shTarget4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("5")
Set shTarget5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("6")
Set shTarget6 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("7")

'Locate the rows to be checked
'2
If shTarget1.Cells(3, 6).Value = "" Then
a = 3
Else
a = shTarget1.Cells(3, 6).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 3
End If

'3
If shTarget2.Cells(3, 6).Value = "" Then
b = 3
Else
b = shTarget2.Cells(3, 6).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 3
End If

'4
If shTarget3.Cells(3, 6).Value = "" Then
c = 3
Else
c = shTarget3.Cells(3, 6).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 3
End If

'5
If shTarget4.Cells(3, 6).Value = "" Then
d = 3
Else
d = shTarget4.Cells(3, 6).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 3
End If

'6
If shTarget5.Cells(3, 6).Value = "" Then
e = 3
Else
e = shTarget5.Cells(3, 6).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 3
End If

'7
If shTarget6.Cells(3, 6).Value = "" Then
f = 3
Else
f = shTarget6.Cells(3, 6).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 3
End If


i = 3

'Do while that will read the data of the cells in the 5th column and if it is match for the string variables, it will move the entire row to the worksheet of the same name
Do While i <= 200
    '2
    If Cells(i, 6).Value = "2" Then
    shSource.Rows(i).Copy
    shTarget1.Cells(a, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    shSource.Rows(i).Delete
    a = a + 1
    GoTo Line1

    '3
    ElseIf Cells(i, 6).Value = "3" Then
    shSource.Rows(i).Copy
    shTarget2.Cells(b, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    shSource.Rows(i).Delete
    b = b + 1
    GoTo Line1
    End If

    '4
    If Cells(i, 6).Value = "4" Then
    shSource.Rows(i).Copy
    shTarget3.Cells(c, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    shSource.Rows(i).Delete
    c = c + 1
    GoTo Line1

    '5
    ElseIf Cells(i, 6).Value = "5" Then
    shSource.Rows(i).Copy
    shTarget4.Cells(d, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    shSource.Rows(i).Delete
    d = d + 1
    GoTo Line1
    End If

    '6
    If Cells(i, 6).Value = "6" Then
    shSource.Rows(i).Copy
    shTarget5.Cells(e, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    shSource.Rows(i).Delete
    e = e + 1
    GoTo Line1

    '7
    ElseIf Cells(i, 6).Value = "7" Then
    shSource.Rows(i).Copy
    shTarget6.Cells(f, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    shSource.Rows(i).Delete
    f = f + 1
    GoTo Line1
    End If

    i = i + 1


Line1:     Loop

    Set mysheet = ActiveSheet
    Dim wrksht As Worksheet
    For Each wrksht In Worksheets

    wrksht.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Next wrksht
    mysheet.Select

End Sub
```

I get the "Run Time Error 9, Subscript out of range".

The reason I get this error is because the sheet does not exist.
So for example, when the sheets are being created based on their cell values and in the cell there's no actual number 4, then a sheet with the name "4" will obviously not be created.

Ideally I wanted to code it in a way that didn't require hard coded string variables to do the check, but I simply don't know how to create that dynamic piece of code. So this is what I have at the moment and I am hoping someone can either help clean up the code to not have hard coded variables (1,2,3,4...) and perhaps just do a check first if the sheet exists then look for the sheet name in the column OR do the same thing but just input some kind of if statement to determine if the sheet exists before it bombs out.

I'm thinking of something like:

```
If (sheet.name("4") exists) Then
Set shTarget4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("4")
Else
Resume
```

There's no need for me to keep the original sheet's data as this is not the source sheet.

The data from the first sheet comes from its source via means of a macro, so if I ever need to refer to the source data then it wont be an issue.

Also, the other reason is that each sheet will be saved as individual workbooks in a folder when my macro's are run so that I can send off each individual sheet to their respective departments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it.  Should be OK provided the values in Col F are valid sheet names.

```
Sub CopyData()

    Dim shtSrc As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, ws, r As Long, v

    Set shtSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each c In shtSrc.Range(shtSrc.Cells(2, 6), shtSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = c.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            With GetSheet(ThisWorkbook, v)
                'first row with no value in ColF
                r = .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                If r < 3 Then r = 3     'start at 3rd row
                .Rows(r).Value = c.EntireRow.Value 'copy row content (value only)
            End With
        End If
    Next c

End Sub


'Return a worksheet from a workbook: if not there, create a new sheet
'  with the supplied name and return that
Function GetSheet(wb As Workbook, theName) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(theName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
        ws.Name = theName
    End If
    Set GetSheet = ws
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

as for your explicit question (looking for some `If (sheet.name("4") exists) Then` way) you could take advantage of this helper function:

```
Function IsSheetThere(shtName As String, sht As Worksheet) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = Worksheets(shtName)
    IsSheetThere = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```

to be used like:

```
Dim targetSht As Worksheet
If IsSheetThere("4", targetSht) Then
    ... (code to handle existing sheet)
End If
```

While as for the more general request ("dynamic piece of code"), you could use [AutoFilter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel) method of `Range` object to formerly filter your *source* sheet column F and then copy/paste values to proper *target* sheet in one shot

I'm assuming that:

- "1" is the worksheet whose column 6 cells you want to loop through from row 3 to the last one and copy/paste entire rows to a target sheet whose name matches current cell value
- *source* sheet column 6 has a header in row 2

  ```
  Sub CopyRowData()
  Dim sourceSht  As Worksheet
  Set sourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1")

  Dim iSht As Long
  Dim targetSht As Worksheet
  With sourceSht
      With .Range("F2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
          For iSht = 2 To 7
              If IsSheetThere(CStr(iSht), targetSht) Then
                  .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=iSht
                  If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
                      Intersect(.Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow, .Parent.UsedRange).Copy
                      With targetSht
                          .Cells(WorksheetFunction.Max(3, .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row), 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                          .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                      End With
                      Application.CutCopyMode = False
                  End If
              End If
          Next
      End With
      .AutoFilterMode = False
  End With
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Thank you for these answers! I will give both a try and let you know how it goes. I am genuinely more keen on the AutoFilter() because its better programming practice, so thank you!

Comment: I used the code for the AutoFilter() with the function there and executed the code, and nothing happened. I commented out the "On Error Resume Next" in the function and got a "subscript our of range" error. Any suggestions @DisplayName?

Comment: hard to say without actual data view. you may want to debug line by line by pressing F8 and checking relevant variables values in immediate window to see what's going on.